# How to make a tabbar such that the first tab of the tabbar should not remain selected

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have created a Windows application.in my `appdelegate` I have called a controller class named **analogcontroller** and added this class to my window so that when I run my application the page that should come first is this page that contains an analog clock with five `tabbaritems` in it each calling different class.

So in the analog controller class xib I have added a `tabbar` with 5 `tabbaritems` in it. But when I run my application the page that gets opened is the page of the firsttabbaritem instead of **analogcontroller**. I want that when I run my application my xib of analog controller should be called with 5 tabbar items below it and when I click on particular tabbaritem then only its corresponding page should be opened, otherwise not. How is this possible?

Comment: -1: While people around here usually are more than willing to do basic cleanup tasks on your question; at least a modicum of effort *is* necessary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the Tab bar item 1 to be selected by default in iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325780/how-to-set-the-tab-bar-item-1-to-be-selected-by-default-in-iphone)

Comment: The accepted answer is nothing more than a link to another question, so this question can be regarded as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

you can set tabbar selected index to your desired tab index  it starts from 0

you can write something like tabbarcontroller.tabbar.selectedindex =1;

Forgive syntax errors... you should try this. xCode is rich editor.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a visible tabBarController, then something will necessarily be selected. No way around this.

However, if you would like to hide the tabBar, then you can certainly do that, either by setting its hidden property to YES or by presenting a modal view on top of the selected tab (e.g. the first viewController).

similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771972/how-to-deselect-tab-when-application-is-loaded)